# Is the volume of a protein substrate equal before and after an enzymatic reaction? (pepsin degrading egg white suspension)

Tags: experimental-chemistry, ph

I am trying to determine the reaction rate of pepsin at different pH values by performing an experiment.

I am using egg-white suspension as the substrate and am adding differently concentrated $\ce{HCl}$ to the substrate to vary the pH of the reaction. Eventually, I add the enzyme. However, for the reaction rate I require the time and the substrate disappeared and product formed.

Is the volume of the egg-white suspension different before and after the enzymatic reaction so that I could use it to calculate the reaction rate or does the protein's volume remain the same after the reaction?

Answer (score 2):

The volume of the protein will probably change (although not by much) because it will be denatured as it is degraded and as the pH decreases. As it denatures, the hydrophilic surface area and hydrophobic interior volume will change, leading to a change in the local water liquid structure and density. Denatured, short polypeptides also pack into smaller volumes than native proteins do, and so that would also cause the volume to decrease in most cases. The amount of water in the system will affect the magnitude of the change. I would predict that the volume would decrease slightly, probably on the order of what happens with a few degrees of temperature increase of water (around 0.1%).

So, the short answer is "Yes, the volume will change, but probably not consistently or by enough to be used to reliably measure the extent of the reaction."

This is not my area of expertise, so I don't know what the current standard protocols are for determining reaction rates for pepsin reactions. However, I was able to find a couple of research papers that talk about using [ninhydrin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninhydrin) to measure reaction extent:

[The pH-Dependence of Pepsin-Catalyzed Reactions](http://bip.cnrs-mrs.fr/bip10/CBKnowles69.pdf)

[Kinetics of Hydrolysis of Egg White Protein by Pepsin](http://www.agriculturejournals.cz/publicFiles/28541.pdf)

In the second study, they quenched the reaction at a specific time by adding NaOH to bring the pH up, then centrifuged the products before measuring the reaction extent.

If this is not a professional scientific study (meaning it's a school project, or something like that) then you might look at the method used in this report:

[The Effect of pH on the Reaction between Pepsin and Egg – White](https://www.scribd.com/doc/94539412/The-Effect-of-pH-on-the-Reaction-between-Pepsin-and-Egg-White-REPORT)

Basically, they just added pepsin and watched to see how long it took for the solution to become "clear". This won't give you very good accuracy or precision, but it might work for a science project or school report.